# How do I import a manually created Android Gradle project into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've updated my project to use the new Gradle based Android build system for various reasons.  I love the new system, and I'm a text editor/command line guy, so it's not a problem.  My favorite thing is that my build is now 16 seconds, instead of a minute or so.

I'm having problems importing the project into Android Studio, however.  I've tried several times, but I can't get it to work right.

I should not that the project is structured like the new Gradle projects should be, not like the old ant ones.  You can see my structure here:

[image]

As for whats happening.  I'm trying to import the project by selecting the root directory, then choosing "Import project from existing model: Gradle".

After that it tells me that it can't find the Gradle Home, so I set it to `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/1.6/libexec`, the install location that Homebrew put gradle for me.

When I click next it does it's thing, then puts up the following error.

[image]

That's also exactly what the console log says, so I'm not quite sure what's going on.  Command line builds work just fine using `./gradlew assembleDebug installDebug` or `...Release`.

I've tried import the project using "Create project from existing sources" but that gets a weird structure to my modules that can't build.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When importing, select the build.gradle file at the root of your project, not your project folder itself.

Comment: That ends in the same result.  It seems to find the build.gradle file appropriately if you select the project folder.